# Built-in keyboard no longer detected after update

Tags: keyboard, manjaro

I am running a Manjaro installation and after a recent update my built-in laptop keyword does no longer work. It does work though in a different distro and in the BIOS so there must be some sort of software problem here.

I have now plugged in another keyboard via USB which works just fine (it is also listed with `lsusb` as the only keyboard but I guess the built-in won't appear there anyway).

Does someone know what might be the issue and how to fix it?

If it is important: My machine is a HP Pavilion laptop.

Comment: You've found a bug, so fill a bugreport: https://bugs.manjaro.org/ (if it doesn't exist yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with libinput.

Uninstall libinput and install libinput-1.8

That solved the problem for me. ( Using manjaro and HP pavillion laptop)